# Need Regular Expression for Format -xx-xxx-x-

Tags: php, regex

I need to parse product ID from URL passed. Length of the URL is uncertain so the product IDs. URLs could be like

```
http://<hostname>/p/Brand-Product-Name-6118-161-1-gallery.jpg
```

OR

```
http://<hostname>/p/Brand-Product-Name-165-7128-12-gallery.jpg
```

I want middle numeric value in any case i.e.(161 and 7128). My programing language is PHP.

Comment: and what have you tried ? By reading up basic tutorials you would have known how to do this.

Comment: That's one of the simplest possible regexen. Have you tried anything?

Comment: here, take my -1. read the FAQs next time.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but didn't find anything. That would be great if you could help. I am not here to waste anyone's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

$url = "http://<hostname>/p/Brand-Product-Name-6118-161-1-gallery.jpg";

preg_match_all('#(\d+)-(\d+)-\d+-gallery\.jpg$#',$url,$matches);
// Depends on how accurate you want to be. You can go with many choices like:
// preg_match_all('#http\://.*?/p/.*?(\d+)-(\d+)-\d+-.*\.jpg#',$url,$matches);

var_dump($matches);

/*
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(22) "6118-161-1-gallery.jpg"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "6118"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "161"
  }
}
*/
```

Comment: No need to escape `-` outside of a `[]` character group.